# Proving that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ iff $\phi(f(x))$ is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

This is what I'm proving:

> Let $F$ be a field. Let $\phi : F[x]\to F[x]$ be an isomorphism such that $\phi(a)=a$ for every $a\in F$. Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ iff $\phi(f(x))$ is.

Here is my proof:

> We prove the contrapositive, i.e. $\phi(f(x))$ is reducible iff $f(x)$ is.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Let $f(x)$ be reducible, i.e. $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for some $g(x),h(x)\in F[x]$ such that $0<\deg(g(x))<\deg(f(x))$ and $0<\deg(h(x))<\deg(f(x))$. Now since $\phi$ is an isomorphism we have $\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x)h(x))=\phi(g(x))\phi(h(x))$ and thus $\phi(f(x))$ is reducible.
>
> ($\Rightarrow$) Let $\phi(f(x))$ be reducible in $F[x]$.
> Now $\phi(f(x))=m(x)n(x)$ for some $m(x),n(x)\in F[x]$ such that $0<\deg(m(x))<\deg(\phi(f(x)))$ and $0<\deg(n(x))<\deg(\phi(f(x)))$. Now since $\phi$ is an isomorphism or rings, so is $\phi^{-1}$, and thus we have $f(x)=\phi^{-1} (\phi(f(x)))=\phi^{-1}(m(x)n(x))=$ $\phi^{-1}(m(x))\phi^{-1}(n(x))$, and hence $f(x)$ is reducible.

Can this be right since I never had to use the fact that $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in F$? If my proof is correct and I used this fact implicitly, I would like to know where. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say that you need $\phi(a) = a$ to show that $\phi(g(x))$ and $\phi^{-1}(g(x))$ are polynomials and not scalars whenever $g(x)$ is

Comment: (and if someone knows a field $F$ and an isomorphism $F[x] \to F[x]$ with $\phi(a) \ne a$ for some $a \in F$ I'd appreciate)

Comment: Yes! I see now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user1952009 has a very good answer, but I have different one throwing some more light on the topic hopefully.

The point is, it's certainly true that $\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x))\phi(h(x))$. However,$\phi(f(x))$ is reducible if and only if *both $\phi(g(x))$ and $\phi(h(x))$ are not scalars*. What if one of them were a scalar? That's why you need the condition that the function fixes $F$.

By the way, suppose that $\sigma$ is an automorphism from $F[x]$ to $F[x]$ fixing $F$.For $\sigma$ to be invertible,think about what the image of the element $x \in F[x]$ should be. Suppose it is some $y$, then $\phi(f(x))$ can be written as $f(y)$, with $y$ being the image of $x$. When will $f(y)$ cover the whole of $F[x]$? Only when $y$ itself is a one-degree polynomial, say $y=ax+b$, because only then can you define the inverse function, $\sigma^{-1}$ neatly, as $\sigma^{-1}(y)=\frac{y-b}{a}=x$, and $\sigma^{-1}$ fixes $F$. So now you know the general form of any such automorphism: it is of the form $f(ax+b)$, where $a,b$ are fixed scalars in $F$.

Now the proof is quite easy: If $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x))\phi(h(x)) = g(ax+b)h(ax+b)$ and the degree of $g(a+bx)$ and $h(a+bx)$ are the same as $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ respectively, whence $\phi(f(x))$ is also reducible. Similarly, you can show the other way using the inverse function.

As a reply to user1952009's question, we can take any polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ and send it to it's conjugate polynomial (conjugate each coefficient). For example, send $(1+i)x$ to $(1-i)x$. This is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ that does not fix $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Great answer, that is helpful to me. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to know. I hope you have understood the invertibility part of my answer, because I thought it wasn't well explained.

Comment: but $f(x) = f(x)/2$ it is not a ring automorphism $\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x]$ since $f(1^2) \ne f(1) f(1)$, I think we need an algebraic extension $L/K$ of some field $K$ with a non-trivial Galois group, then with $f$ an automorphism $L \to L$ that fixes $K$ we get $f(a) = a$ for every $a \in K$ but not for every $a \in L$,  and it yields an automorphism  $L[x] \to L[x]$. but it doesn't change the reducibility of polynomials.

Comment: @user1952009 I am sorry. I will edit my answer. Actually with the real numbers what you say is true,which is that the only automorphism is the identity.

Comment: I think if $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism of $F[x]$ onto itself, then $\phi$ restricts to a field isomorphism $F \rightarrow F$, and necessarily $\phi(x) = ax+b$ for some $a,b\in F$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the fact that $\phi$ fixes $F$.  If $A$ is a commutative ring with identity, an element $f \in A$ is defined to be irreducible if and only if whenever $g, h \in A$ and $f = gh$, you have $g$ or $h$ is a unit in $A$. If $\psi: A \rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism of rings, then it sends units to units, so it must send irreducible things to irreducibles.

Check that a polynomial $f \in F[X]$ is irreducible in this sense if and only if it is irreducible in the sense you're saying (use the fact that the units in $F[X]$ are exactly the nonzero constant polynomials).

**Edit**: By the way, the possibility that $\phi(g)$ is a scalar when $g$ is not, can't happen.  This is because $\phi$ sends units to units, so it sends elements of $F \setminus \{0\}$ to themselves.  In other words, $\phi$ may not be the identity on $F$, *but the restriction of $\phi$ to $F$ is an isomorphism of $F$ onto itself*.

More generally, if $f(X) \in F[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then $\phi(f)$ will also have degree $d$, regardess of whether or not $\phi$ fixes $F$.

Proof: Since $\phi$ is completely determined by its effect on $F$ and on $X$, it is enough to show that $\phi(X) = aX+b$ for some $b,0 \neq a \in F$.  Already you know that $\phi(X)$ must have degree at least one.  But then its degree must be exactly one: every element of $F[X]$ is obtained by taking finitely many nonnegative powers of $X$, multiplying each power by some element of $F$, and adding everything together.  Hence the same must be true for $\phi(X)$.  So if $\phi(X)$ had degree $>1$, you would not be able to obtain linear polynomials from these combinations of $\phi(X)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for that very clear answer. I understand it better now. :)